# Check DT Picker Results, copy sheet into new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

my VBA skills aren't the best, if someone could help with the following that would be great.

I have a number of sheets in a workbook that has a date record in the cell range E11:E37.

I'm trying to create a reporting function whereby the user completes a date picker userform, Excel runs a search on the above range in all worksheets in this workbook for a date that falls between the DTPicker1/2 results.

For sheets that return a match, copy all those sheets to a new workbook with name ("Name & current Date".xlsx).

Update: I tried reversing the > and <, no change, think i wrapped in Cdate for the DTPicker Values no results, did both, no results....

Update: code now working but doesnt return a value true where dates in range = 01/06/18 - 14/06/18 where DTP1 = 07/06/18 and DTP2 = 16/06/18. But does return true where DTP1 = 04/06/18 and DTP2 = 08/06/18.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim s As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

For Each s In Worksheets
    If CBool(Application.CountIfs(s.Range("E11:E37"), ">" & 
CDate(DTPicker1.Value), _
                                  s.Range("E11:E37"), "<" & 
CDate(DTPicker2.Value))) Then
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            s.Copy
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Else
            s.Copy after:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)
        End If
    End If
Next s

If wb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No Records Found")
Else
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="Technicians - Batch Record Report" & Format(Date, 
"ddmmyyyy"), _
          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the form look like? Where's the problem? What have you tried? If you hard code the dates does everything else work fine?

Comment: @ashleedawg ... Sorry about this! I am getting a missmatch error on ine: If Range("I11:I37") > DTPicker1.Value And Range("I11:I37") < DTPicker2.Value Then. Because of this, i cant actually get any further to see if the copy functionality works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to see if it gets you closer to your goal.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim s As Worksheet, wb as workbook

    For Each s In workSheets
        If cbool(application.countifs(s.Range("I11:I37"), ">" & cdate(DTPicker1.Value), _
                                      s.Range("I11:I37"), "<" & cdate(DTPicker2.Value))) then
            if wb is nothing then
                s.copy
                set wb = activeworkbook
            else
                s.copy after:=wb.worksheets(wb.worksheets.count)
            end if
        end if
    next s

    if wb is nothing then
        MsgBox ("No Records Found")
    else
        wb.SaveAs Filename:="Technicians - Batch Record Report" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy"), _
              FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code appears to be working however it returns "No Records Found when there are records that meet the criteria. Would it be because the timestamp includes the time and the date picker value doesnt?

Comment: Perhaps your DTPicker1 and DTPicker2 are not true dates. Try wrapping them in cdate. Maybe you have the `>` and `<` reversed.

Comment: I can use a hardcoded date instead by including it in the document. Having done this and amended the code to look at the new range (E11:E37) i still get "no results"...

Comment: Must be your data and/or DTPicker1/2. This works for me with hard-coded dates.

Comment: Any chance i could share it with you? Just treid it by removing dtpicker from the code and refering to sheet cells with dates hard coded and still no results?

Comment: Ok weird, IT works if all fields in the range have a date in them, sometimes only one of the fields in this range will have a qualifying date. any way around this?

Comment: So the range has the following dates 01/06/18,.....,14/06/18. When running the DTpicker where DTp1=08/06/18 and DTP2 = 16/06/18 i get no results... but when DTP1=04/06/18 and DTP2= 09/06/18 the code works...

Comment: vba likes en-us date format. you're using dmy instead of mdy in your picker.

Comment: So there is no way to use dym then?  would the following code be appropraite to change the formate to mm/dd/yyy?                                                         
Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
End Sub

Comment: Well, sure. You could change it to mdy or eveb a long integer; either will work.